# How to change value of label from another UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, collectionview

What if the UILabel is in class A and the `didTapRightutton` that will animate it is in class B?

the `percentDiscountLabel` is in `RandomizeDealsCollectionViewCell`. This should animate into fade appear if I tap `didTapRightutton` which is in a different VC called `RandomizeDealsViewController`

How do I call the function that is inside `RandomizeDealsCollectionViewCell` to animate the `percentDiscountLabel`? Is there other way to do this?

```
class RandomizeDealsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var percentDiscountLabel: UILabel!

    func animatePercentDiscountLabel(deals: String) {

        self.percentDiscountLabel.alpha = 0.6
        self.percentDiscountLabel.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.percentDiscountLabel.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (isCompleted) in
        }
        percentDiscountLabel.text = deals
    }

}


class RandomizeDealsViewController: UIViewController {

private var centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout: CenteredCollectionViewFlowLayout!

    @IBAction func didTapRightButton(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let indexCard = centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.currentCenteredPage else { return }
        if (indexCard > 0) {
             centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.scrollToPage(index: indexCard + 1, animated: true)
             // should call the animation function here

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the `currentCenteredPage` ?

Answer (score 1):

If `indexCard` is `indexPath` of collectionViewCell which you want to animate,

You can call your cell like ->

**in RandomizeDealsViewController**

```
@IBAction func didTapRightButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let indexCard = centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.currentCenteredPage else { return }
    if (indexCard > 0) {
         centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.scrollToPage(index: indexCard + 1, animated: true)
        // should call the animation function here
        let cell = collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexCard) as? RandomizeDealsCollectionViewCell
        cell?.animatePercentDiscountLabel(deals: "deals")

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Emre, the function is being called but the animation is not working. I tried the animation to different labels inside RandomizeDealsViewController so the animation should be fine. Not sure why it dont work since it is being called

Comment: This question about calling cell's animation function in viewController. So if you have any other issue please ask one more question about animation block. Then you can find a solution about animation this way easily.